# Image appended to div using jquery is not clickable

Tags: jquery, html, image, click, append

I'm facing an issue trying to click on an image that was appended to a div.

I have a "plus_btn" which adds one or more "closebtn"s to the div when it's clicked. That part works fine, but the next step which is clicking these close buttons does not work. I also have an attribute called "att-id" which i'm trying to get by clicking the closebtn, but the clicks don't take effect.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
var i = 0;
$('#plus_btn').click(function(){
    $("#content").append('<img id="closebtn" class="imgbtn" att-id="'+i+'" width="20" height="20" src="manage/images/closebtn.png">');              
    i++;
});   
$(".imgbtn").click(function(){
    alert('gggg');          
}); 
});
```

and here is my html code:

```
    <img id="plus_btn" src="images/plus_btn.png" width="15" height="15" />
    <div id="content" name="content">
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically inserted content is not listened by default by jQuery, and you need to use the ON method like so:

```
$('#parent_element').on('click', '.class_of_new_dynamic_element_here', function(){ 
   // code here 
}
```

Your working [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/b12svb4s/4)

This happens because jQuery is aware of the DOM that was loaded along with it, any element appended afterwards needs to be specified to jQuery as so.

Hope this helped

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried using the .on instead and removed the id tag, but still no luck! I have the code on jsfiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/b12svb4s/3 
would you please have a look if you get a chance.

Comment: Basically, when using ON, you have to select the parent element and then specify the element you want the eventListener on. That is so jQuery knows where to look precisely, it saves precious DOM traversing. I also updated my answer. Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

use `.on()` instead of click:

```
$(".imgbtn").on('click',function(){
    alert('gggg');          
});
```

Also `id` attributes are unique, so you can not add `#closebtn` every time your button is clicked. I would suggest using class for that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried using the .on instead and removed the id tag, but still no luck! I have the code here as well: http://jsfiddle.net/b12svb4s/3/  
would you please have a look if you get a chance.